# Accuracy metrics output in strange letters

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why is my accuracy output so strange?

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test,predicted)
print(confusion_mat)

from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
precision_score(y_test, predicted, average='weighted')
print(precision_score)


from sklearn.metrics  import precision_recall_fscore_support
precision_recall_fscore_support (y_test,predicted,average=None)
print(precision_recall_fscore_support)
```

Output is this

```
[[31  0  2  0]
 [ 0 23  1  0]
 [ 0  1 26  0]
 [ 0  0  1 40]]

function precision_score at 0x00000167CFB65840

function precision_recall_fscore_support at 0x00000167CFB657B8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing functions location in memory, but you need to print the result of the function. Like that:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
score = precision_score(y_test, predicted, average='weighted')
print(score)
```